# Authentication not granted for service principal token in MS Fabric API using Python

Tags: python, azure, token, azure-service-principal, microsoft-fabric

I am trying to connect to OneLake API in Microsoft Fabric using Python in VScode.

So far I have

1. Registered an app in Azure with these API permissions

[image]

2. Then created a secret for my service principal
3. Then I try to get the token with this function, using azure.identity:

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential, AuthenticationRequiredError

def get_access_token(app_id, client_secret, directory_id):
    try:
        # Create the ClientSecretCredential using the provided credentials
        credential = ClientSecretCredential(
            client_id=app_id,
            client_secret=client_secret,
            tenant_id=directory_id
            #scope="https://storage.azure.com/.default"
        )

        # Use the credential to get the access token
        token = credential.get_token("https://storage.azure.com/.default").token

        return token, credential

    except AuthenticationRequiredError as e:
        print("Authentication failed. Please check your credentials.")
        raise e

    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred while getting the access token:")
        print(str(e))
        raise e
    
access_token, credential = get_access_token(app_id, client_secret, directory_id)
```

It seems I get the token fine and all. But there is something wrong with the permissions or scope or access. Because when I run this function to check for connection i get status code 400

```
def check_connection_with_onelake(access_token):
    base_url = "https://onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/9c3ffd43-b537-4ca2-b9ba-0c59d0094033/Files/sample?resource=file" 
    token_headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
    }

    try:
        response = requests.put(base_url, headers=token_headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Connection with OneLake is successful.")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect with OneLake. Status code:", response.status_code)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("An error occurred while checking the connection:", str(e))

# Assuming 'access_token' is already defined and contains a valid access token
check_connection_with_onelake(access_token)
```

4. I also added the app's service principal to users in the Fabric workspace as an admin

[image]

**Where am I missing access and how do I grant the correct access?**

references:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/onelake/onelake-access-api
https://amitchandak.medium.com/on-premise-python-code-to-local-sql-server-data-to-microsoft-fabric-lakehouse-using-token-d15b8795e349

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **API permissions** as below:

[image]

In my Fabric Workspace, I added above service principal as **Admin** same as you:

[image]

When I ran your python code in my environment, I too got **status code 400**. To know the exact error, I printed **content** of response like this:

```py
import requests
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential, AuthenticationRequiredError

def get_access_token(app_id, client_secret, directory_id):
    try:
        # Create the ClientSecretCredential using the provided credentials
        credential = ClientSecretCredential(
            client_id=app_id,
            client_secret=client_secret,
            tenant_id=directory_id
            #scope="https://storage.azure.com/.default"
        )

        # Use the credential to get the access token
        token = credential.get_token("https://storage.azure.com/.default").token

        return token, credential

    except AuthenticationRequiredError as e:
        print("Authentication failed. Please check your credentials.")
        raise e

    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred while getting the access token:")
        print(str(e))
        raise e
    
access_token, credential = get_access_token("appId", "secret", "tenantId")


def check_connection_with_onelake(access_token):
    base_url = "https://onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/0f0050d1-5601-47d0-9eb6-xxxxxxx/Files/sample?resource=file" 
    token_headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
    }

    try:
        response = requests.put(base_url, headers=token_headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Connection with OneLake is successful.")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect with OneLake. Status code:", response.status_code)
            print(response.content)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("An error occurred while checking the connection:", str(e))

# Assuming 'access_token' is already defined and contains a valid access token
check_connection_with_onelake(access_token)
```

**Response:**

[image]

> The error occurred as you missed adding **`LakehouseId`** after
> workspace ID in your base URL and you need to use **GET** request to
> check connection by removing `resource=file`.

You can find **`LakehouseId`** in address bar after */lakehouses/* when you open it in browser like this:

[image]

When I ran below modified code by changing the `base_url` and request type, I got **response** successfully like below:

```py
import requests
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential, AuthenticationRequiredError

def get_access_token(app_id, client_secret, directory_id):
    try:
        # Create the ClientSecretCredential using the provided credentials
        credential = ClientSecretCredential(
            client_id=app_id,
            client_secret=client_secret,
            tenant_id=directory_id
            #scope="https://storage.azure.com/.default"
        )

        # Use the credential to get the access token
        token = credential.get_token("https://storage.azure.com/.default").token

        return token, credential

    except AuthenticationRequiredError as e:
        print("Authentication failed. Please check your credentials.")
        raise e

    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred while getting the access token:")
        print(str(e))
        raise e
    
access_token, credential = get_access_token("appId", "secret", "tenantId")


def check_connection_with_onelake(access_token):
    base_url = "https://onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/0f0050d1-5601-47d0-9eb6-xxxxxxx/37a6ca4e-27b6-437b-800c-xxxxxxxxxx/Files/sample" 
    token_headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
    }

    try:
        response = requests.get(base_url, headers=token_headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Connection with OneLake is successful.")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect with OneLake. Status code:", response.status_code)
            print(response.content)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print("An error occurred while checking the connection:", str(e))

# Assuming 'access_token' is already defined and contains a valid access token
check_connection_with_onelake(access_token)
```

**Response:**

[image]